# Input characters with getche and store it to the array

Tags: c

i want to input character and store it to the array `StringTemp[5][50]`. it will stop input character if i press enter button. but it's not working

```
char StringTemp[5][50];
char c;
int i,o;
i = 1;
o = 1;

c = getche();
while (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
    if (c == ' ') {
        i++;
        o = 1;
    }
    else {
        StringTemp[i][o] = c;
        o++;
    }
    c = getche();
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: 1) `i = 1; o = 1;` --> `i = 0; o = 0;` start with `0`. 2) `char c;` --> `int c;` 3) The C string must end with 0.

Comment: You should probably be using `int c;` to avoid mishandling ÿ.  You should also prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: why used 'int' to store a character?

Comment: Please use `int c` because `getche()` returns that type, and also so that `EOF` is distingishable from `0xFF`. You should also test for `0` and `224` which are used as "escape" codes before the next code from a function key and/or cursor key.

Comment: `EOF` isn't `char`.

Comment: @WeatherVane and how about the array? i want to store a characters and if i input space it will store to the next index

Comment: @FladioArmandika: You really should get a C book and work through the chapters. Your questions should be explained there and you will get the whole picture. You will not get it from asking particular questions or watching youtube videos (which are also often wrong).

Comment: @FladioArmandika that depends on what you want to do with the array, but please note that most of the C library functions which beginners assume will take or return `char` do not, they use the `int` type. For example `putch()` and `toupper()` and `isalpha()` and `getchar()` the list goes on.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are variation depending on keyboard and stdin, but getche() gets the key without echoing. When the user types Enter, the un C-ified char may be '\n' or '\r'. When this is printed you get the corresponding line-feed or carriage return. Since Enter maps to '\r' on your keyboard, when fetched via getche(), test for that and print '\n'. When fetched via getchar(), C translates the Enter to '\n'.

   int ch = getche();

   if (ch == '\r') c = '\n';

   printf("%c", ch);
2. Use int c so code can check for EOF.